# Robots: block /lang/page from the index but keep /page

Tags: url, web-crawlers, robots.txt

My URL structure looks a bit like this:

- `/group1/`
- `/group2/`
- `/group3/`

`Group3` (and it's subpages) are also available in another language at the following URLs. A lang prefix was added to this URL:

- `/lang/group3/`

Unfortunately, a CMS upgrade has caused the following URLs to now considered valid, even though they have not been translated.

- `/lang/group1`
- `/lang/group2`

I would like to allow `/group3` and `/lang/group3` but block `/lang/group*` from the index.

What is the correct robots syntax to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally only have a few "groups" you want to block then you would do something like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /lang/group1
Disallow: /lang/group2
```

...and everything else would be allowed. This would work with all robots that obey the original "standard". Or, you could block *all* groups (`group1`, `group2`, etc.) and make an exception for "group3", like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /lang/group
Allow: /lang/group3
```

Note that the `Allow` directive is not part of the original "standard", but has universal support. The URL path is simply a *prefix*.

HOWEVER, I wouldn't use robots.txt to block the pages being "crawled". What about stray visitors? And bad bots? And robots.txt doesn't prevent pages from being indexed if they are inadvertently linked to. I would use .htaccess or your server config to actually block all traffic to these URLs. Something like the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lang/group[12] - [R=404]
```

To respond with a 404 for all requests to these invalid URLs. Or, use the `F` flag to respond with a 403 "Forbidden".

Comment: Thanks, there are many thousands 'groups' I'm afraid. I agree .htaccess would be better. Would a pattern like Disallow: /lang/* Allow: /lang/group3 be considered valid?

Comment: Yes that would be valid, although the `*` at the end of the URL path is unnecessary (and a modern addition to the standard). The URL path is just a prefix anyway.